# How to access a <ul> list element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

there. I have a div with a list of links in it and I'm trying to store one of the links in a jquery variable, but I'm not sure how to reach it. Unfortunately I can edit the divs or lists directly to add ids (its a yahoo store site), so i need to traverse the object tree.

Here's my practice code

```
   <div id="newDiv">
        <div id="newerDiv">
            <div id= "squareDiv" style="width: 100px; border:2px solid #a1a1a1;" >Square
            <ul>
                <li><a title="Inca" href="mainazag.html">Maya Inca Aztec</a> </li>
                <li><a title="Maya" href="mainazag.html">Maya Inca Aztec</a> </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is what I was trying to do access the link with title Maya:

```
var listitem = $("#squareDiv").find("a[title='Maya']");
```

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `ul` is not a descendant of `#squareDiv`, it is the next sibling. Also the anchor element does not have a class called `a` so the class selector will not work, you need to use element selector

```
var listitem = $("#squareDiv").next().find("a[title='Maya']");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KGBcF/)

or use the parent `div` id `newerDiv` whose child is the `ul` element

```
var listitem = $("#newerDiv").find("a[title='Maya']");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/V9H8Y/)

Comment: sorry that was typo. the <ul> is inside the #squareDiv

Comment: @WillTuttle the the problem is the class selector `.a` as I updated in the answer... you need to use the element selector `"a[title='Maya']"`